# React-native UI not rendering properly when clicked on push notifications in IOS 15

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, aws-amplify

I had integrated push notification in my react native application. when I click on the push notification (removed app instance) my application opens and it navigates to the Home screen but UI does not render (styles are not applied to UI). it happens only in IOS. Android works fine

**my versions**

```
"@aws-amplify/pushnotification": "^3.2.32"
"aws-amplify": "4.3.7"
"aws-amplify-react-native": "6.0.1"
"@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "1.9.0"
"react": "16.13.1"
"react-native": "0.63.4"
```

I am using PushNotification.onNotificationOpened outside the hooks class.

Styles are loaded from external StyleSheet

**sample code**

```
`import PushNotification from '@aws-amplify/pushnotification'`

PushNotification.onNotificationOpened(notification => {
    let obj = notification["_data"]["data"]["jsonBody"]
    setTimeout(()=>{
      notificationAPI(obj.id)
    },1000)
});

const Home = ({route, navigation}) =>{

useEffect(() => {
APICall()
  })
}, [isVisible]);

return (
 <View>
**CUSTOME UI**
</View>
)
}

export default Home;
```

How can I solve this issue when I click on push notifications UI should render properly with all the styles applied.

**Original UI**

[image]

**when I click on push notification app opens and styles does not apply.**

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem but only on devices which have ios 15+. What software version do you have on your testing devices?

Comment: I have tested in ios 15.1

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: No not yet. Which versions are you using

Comment: 14.6, 15.0, 15.1 but I couldn't reproduce on 14.6.

Comment: Are you using the same react versions that i used?

Comment: "react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",

Comment: I have also facing same issue any one have solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my XCODE and macOS, archive again and this build looks fine now.
xcode version: 13.1
macOS version: 12.0.1

Comment: Thanks denisas After updating Xcode to 13.1 it's working fine but there are some minor issues.

Comment: If we release builds from XCode 12 it has only support for ios 14 so we are getting issues in ios 15 devices.